# If a group $G$ is infinite, prove that it has a non-trivial subgroup

Tags: group-theory, infinite-groups

I am working on some elementary group theory problems and one of them states:

"Show that an infinite group $G$ has to contain a non-trivial
subgroup, i.e. a subgroup $\neq G$, {$e$}."

My process:$$G:\{a,b,...,e,a^{-1},b^{-1}...\}$$

So a possible subgroup could be $$G_{s}: \{a,a^{-1},e\}$$ Since $$a*a^{-1}=e$$ $$a*e=a$$ $$a^{-1}*e=a^{-1}$$ are all contained within the subgroup.

Is this approach valid? I feel like I'm missing something...

EDIT: Totally forgot about $a*a$, could anyone give me any hints on how to approach this problem?

Comment: And what about $a*a$?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I did not even realize that. Now I am even more lost on how to approach this.

Comment: You need to consider two cases. 1) There is an element of the group of infinite order, this is the easy case. 2) There are no elements of infinite order. This case is even easier.

Comment: @StephenMeskin I see, so would that mean that the subgroup would consist of a single element of infinite order? As well as a subgroup containing every element but the one with infinite order?

Comment: In case 1)  there are two sub cases. a) G is generated by the element of infinite order. b) G is not so generated. Further comments on your comment A) a subgroup cannot consist of a single element and B) the set of all elements not belonging to a subgroup does not form a subgroup of its own.

Comment: Ok thank you, I was not aware of that.

Comment: I suggest you review the definitions of subgroup and group. And review some examples.

Comment: @Moishe Cohen I agree that this looks like a duplicate, but IMO this student would need to jump over a number of hurdles to understand the proof(s) given for the alleged "exact" duplicate. And even the equivalence of the statements might cause a problem. So I ask you to withdraw your vote. Thanks.

Comment: @Trevor Gunn see my comment directed to Moishe Cohen

Comment: @Community see my comment directed to Moishe Cohen

Comment: @Stephen aleden accepted the duplicate, that's what the vote by the Community user means. Furthermore, you can't withdraw a close vote after a question is closed.

Comment: @Trevor Gunn O the things one learns by making mistakes.